# Writing kill-or-bury-other-buffer in emacs lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to write a function to kill or bury the buffer in the other window based on whether the buffer in the other window has a file bound to it or not.

It seems to work sometimes, and doesn't always pick the buffer in the other window to kill.
Am I using the wrong function or the functions wrong?

```
(defun kill-or-bury-other-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((other-buf (window-buffer (other-window 1 nil)))
         (other-has-file (buffer-file-name other-buf))
         (buf-action (if other-has-file
                           'bury-buffer
                         'kill-buffer)))
    (funcall buf-action other-buf))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition of what @legoscia points to, I think your code would be simpler using `save-selected-window`:

```
(defun kill-or-bury-other-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (save-selected-window
    (other-window 1)
    (if buffer-file-name
        (bury-buffer)
      (kill-buffer))))
```

Comment: I see that buffer-file-name here is a variable as well as a function - is this pretty common in elisp? e.g. (I know the namespaces are split)

Comment: It is not unusual, e.g. many minor modes have a function to toggle them and a variable with same name to store the toggled status.

Answer (score 2):

The function `other-window` *switches* to the other window and returns `nil`.  The call `(window-buffer (other-window 1 nil))` returns the buffer of the other window more of less because of a coincidence, because `(window-buffer nil)` returns the buffer of the current window.  You probably want to use `next-window` instead.  (I'm not sure this explains why the function kills the wrong buffer, though.)